# Where is Dockerfile running in OpenShift Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, openshift

I am trying to send an file to the Docker image while building Jenkins job in OpenShift.

I tried paths, changing directories and some other methods but couldn't achieve anything. I am trying to send files inside my jenkins pod to docker image. Dockerfile only copies its paths. Where is it? Where is Jenkins Pipeline stores that Dockerfile and stashed war file?

```
source:
  dockerfile: |-
    FROM wildfly
    COPY ROOT.war /wildfly/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war
    RUN ls -la .
    CMD $STI_SCRIPTS_PATH/run
  binary:
    asFile: ROOT.war
  type: Docker
strategy:
  dockerStrategy:
    from:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: wildfly:latest
    paths:
    - destinationDir: test
      sourcePath: /tmp/myfile/.
  type: Docker
triggers: []
```

I am expecting to send my /tmp/myfile to the Docker image. Paths not working for me. I tried "COPY . ." but only Dockerfile and ROOT.war existing in that path. What the exact path which includes Dockerfile and ROOT.war? I am thinking about copying file manually to the that path. Is it possible or do you know any other way?

Comment: There is no ```paths``` key in the ```strategy.dockerStrategy``` section. You can see the API documentation for the ```BuildConfig``` object [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/apis-build.openshift.io/v1.BuildConfig.html)

Comment: As you can see I tried everything and nothing happened. Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: One way would be to pull the files from an http server during your docker build via wget/curl.